# xargs - does the program run in loop or get re-executed

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments, execution, xargs

I have a C++ program that is outputting text strings which are read as command line inputs to my Java program. My question is does the Java program continuously run with new inputs given or does the program terminate and then get executed again when new command line arguments are generated?

My command:

```
./ORBMarkerDetection templateImages/smallMarkers/Activities/3.2/chair.png templateImages/smallMarkers/Activities/3.2/cutlery.png  | xargs -n3 java -jar ../../system/layers/out/artifacts/layers_jar/layers.jar
```

EDIT:

So for example if I had a varible in my Java program that I wanted to increment each time the three lines of input are given would it increment each time or after the three lines are processed is the Java program terminated and the variable set back to it's initialisation value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the `-n` argument is as follows:

```
--max-args=max-args, -n max-args
          Use  at  most  max-args  arguments per command line.  Fewer than
          max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s  option)
          is  exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs
          will exit.
```

Hence, using the `-n 3` option, your java command will run once for every three lines of input. Each time it is run, it will (I suppose) loop and process three inputs.

After each group of three lines your Java program will exit and all information in it (loop counters, etc) will be lost.

Comment: Can you add to your answer on the edit I added to the original post?